# Dual core on Raspberry Pi PICO W with MicroPython

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have an issue with running part of a code to be more specific defined as new thread CoreTask().
I have no idea why I cannot turn on/off built-in LED. The rest of the code looks to be working as expected (WIFI integration and 'httpd service' work fine).
I use Raspberry Pi Pico W with latest MicroPython loaded.

Please advice... Thanks!

```
import machine
import _thread
import network
import socket
import utime
from machine import Pin

led = machine.Pin('LED', machine.Pin.OUT)

ssid = 'someSSID'
password = 'somePASSWORD'

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(ssid, password)

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <body>
            <div id="humidity">100</div>
            <div id="temperature">21</div>
        </body>
    </html>
"""

                    
sLock = _thread.allocate_lock()
def CoreTask():
    while True:
        sLock.acquire()
        print('LED...')
        led.on()
        utime.sleep(1)
        led.off()
        utime.sleep(1)
        sLock.release()
_thread.start_new_thread(CoreTask, ())

while True:
    sLock.acquire()
    # Wait for connect or fail
    max_wait = 10
    while max_wait > 0:
        if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
            break
        max_wait -= 1
        print('waiting for connection...')
        utime.sleep(1)
                    
        # Handle connection error
    if wlan.status() != 3:
        raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
    else:
        print('connected')
        status = wlan.ifconfig()
        print( 'ip = ' + status[0] )
                   
    # Open socket
    addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]
        
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(addr)
    s.listen(1)
                   
    print('listening on', addr)
                   
    # Listen for connections
    while True:
        try:
            cl, addr = s.accept()
            print('client connected from', addr)
                      
            request = cl.recv(1024)
            print(request)
                  
            request = str(request)
            response = html
                          
            cl.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
            cl.send(response)
            cl.close()
                   
        except OSError as e:
            cl.close()
            print('connection closed')
                          
        sLock.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also keen to know a solution, so far the best try I have got the onboard led working in seperate thread is the following simple code, every other more complicated try was failed.

I have only tested this with onboard LED, so if anyone may try if threading works on real GPIO? If it does, I think this is not an issue as most of time we send out "status blinks" on other LED in project not the onboard one.

```
import machine
import _thread
import time

def led():
    led = machine.Pin('LED', machine.Pin.OUT)
    while True:
        led.on()
        time.sleep(.5)
        led.off()
        time.sleep(.5)
        
def pnt():
    i=0
    while True:
        i += 1
        print(f"\rThis is the {i} cycle......", sep="", end="")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    th1 = _thread.start_new_thread(pnt, ())
    #th2 = _thread.start_new_thread(led, ()) This line did not work
    led()
```

I think someone said in a video that the threading is still in experiment and has problems on pico w, and they are working on it.

I also could not workout how to achieve same result with uasycncio, it looks like calling the LED to blink is not about programming but real physical movement, so cannot be "await". Can anyone show ma a correct way?

It's is such an important function to waiting for program (connection loop) while sending "status blinks"